# Line Separator/Break in Discord.js Embed Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently working on a Discord Bot with JavaScript and Discord.js and I want to create a welcome Message. The message itself works good, but  my problem is, that I want a line separator in my embed message, but it won't work. In the end it should look like this:

[image]

(Ignore that it's all German, I'm German and the Bot is for a German server too).

When it says "Vergesst nicht" (don't forget (to) in English) I want to have an empty line in the embed.
I already tried \n and \u200B, but none of them works. That's how my code looks like at this point:

```js
.addField("Don't forget to visit", '\u200B╭✧<#808311247203729429>\n ︰<#808295944911192096>\n ╰✧<#808285096213479468>\n\nHave fun! :)')
```

(I translated it to English for you, maybe it's easier for you to help me.)

As you can see, I currently have `\u200B` there, which should (as far as I know) create an empty line. But it doesn't. Everything that comes after it (so the text channel) is in the very next line.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field names and values are trimmed, so all whitespace (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and line terminator characters are removed from both ends of the strings. Using zero-width space was a good idea. If you insert a `\n` between the starting zero-width space (`\u200B`) and the first character, you can add a leading empty line in your embed's field:

```js
.addField(
  "Don't forget to visit",
  '\u200B\n╭✧<#808311247203729429>\n ︰<#808295944911192096>\n ╰✧<#808285096213479468>\n\nHave fun! :)'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might add just a simple `'\n'` to your message:

```
.addField("Don't forget to visit\n\n", '╭✧<#808311247203729429>\n ︰<#808295944911192096>\n ╰✧<#808285096213479468>\n\nHave fun! :)')
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Just because I have to add two values into the brackets behind .addField. No more and no less. So with what you wrote I would have three values, which leads to an error.

Comment: @Hydrablades I edited the code so now it has only 2 arguments

Comment: It still won't work, even if I put another \n in front of the channel ID :/

Comment: @Hydrablades you could try using `\b`